# Load host IConfiguration from supplied command line args;

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core apps configure and launch a host. The host is responsible for app startup and lifetime management by auto-generating a “Program.cs”, which takes care of setting up a host.
According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.host.createdefaultbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0), if you use CreateDefaultBuilder, the following defaults are applied to HostBuilder:

- load host IConfiguration from supplied command line args;
- load app IConfiguration from environment variables;

Does anyone have information on how the arguments affect the CreateDefaultBuilder?
If I pass arguments on the following code, How can I access that?

> static void Main(string[] args)
> {
> IHostBuilder common= Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
> }

Answer (score 1):

I just found out how to use IConfiguration. If you Inject "foo:123" on the arguments, you could store it this way:

```
   IConfiguration Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()


  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)

               .AddEnvironmentVariables()
               .AddCommandLine(args)
               .Build();
   var customSection = Configuration.GetSection("foo");
```